# Joomla, can't install extensions

Tags: joomla3.0, web-application-firewall

I want to install a Joomla extension but I keep get an error:

> Sorry {ip}, your request cannot be proceeded.
>   For security reason, it was blocked and logged.
>
> If you think that was a mistake, please contact the webmaster and enclose the following incident ID:
>
> [ #4677055 ]

I am logged in as superuser. I tried to clear the cache but still no change.

After some investigation I found that this is a problem generated by "ninja", which is a firewall or something.

Comment: If you want to uninstall ninja then here is the link https://nintechnet.com/ninjafirewall/pro-edition/help/

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i can't find in the joomla console the location of this ninja thing

Comment: Please post your Joomla-specific questions on Joomla Stack Exchange to reach a dedicated audience.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a Firewall extension installed that blocks the install action. This could either be NinjaFirewall or AdminTools. Please check for these and others, and remove the block in its configuration. They are most likely under Components or Plugins.

Comment: Thanks, i have solved the problem but you are right. It was ninja firewall